# Where does the Toolbar Metadata live in Visual Studio on the Filesystem

Tags: visual-studio

My IDE crashes any time I try add a new component to the toolbar.  I've already tried Resetting the toolbar.

Where does the the information about the toolbar exist on the filesystem to see what may be the offending control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the location:

C:\users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0

The 4 files: toolbox.tbd, toolbox_reset.tbd, toolboxIndex.tbd, toolboxIndex_reset.tbd